# How to prevent asyncio.Task from being cancelled

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am implementing graceful shutdown that needs to wait for certain tasks to finish execution before shutting down the application. I am waiting for tasks using `asyncio.gather(*asyncio.Task.all_tasks())` in the shutdown handler.

The problem I have however, is that the tasks that are created and need to be waited for, get cancelled as soon as I kill the application and therefore don't appear in `asyncio.Task.get_all()`. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note:* `asyncio.Task.all_tasks()` is [depricated](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#whatsnew37-asyncio-deprecated), will refer it as `asyncio.all_tasks()` instead.

---

### TL;DR Demo code

Different solutions per os type.

- *nix: terminated by sending SIGINT
- Windows: terminated by Ctrl+C

Task duration is set to 10 seconds, so terminate before task completes.

#### Pure asyncio (*nix only)

Complex, long, reinventing the wheels. Adds custom signal handler to prevent error propagation.

Demonstrating spawning 3 shielded & 3 unshielded tasks - former running until completion, latter getting canceled.

```py
"""
Task shielding demonstration with pure asyncio, nix only
"""
import asyncio
import signal
import os


# Sets of tasks we shouldn't cancel
REQUIRE_SHIELDING = set()


async def work(n):
    """Some random io intensive work to test shielding"""
    print(f"[{n}] Task start!")
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        # we shouldn't see following output
        print(f"[{n}] Canceled!")
        return

    print(f"[{n}] Task done!")


def install_handler():

    def handler(sig_name):
        print(f"Received {sig_name}")

        # distinguish what to await and what to cancel. We'll have to await all,
        # but we only have to manually cancel subset of it.
        to_await = asyncio.all_tasks()
        to_cancel = to_await - REQUIRE_SHIELDING

        # cancel tasks that don't require shielding
        for task in to_cancel:
            task.cancel()

        print(f"Cancelling {len(to_cancel)} out of {len(to_await)}")

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    # install for SIGINT and SIGTERM
    for signal_name in ("SIGINT", "SIGTERM"):
        loop.add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, signal_name), handler, signal_name)


async def main():
    print(f"PID: {os.getpid()}")

    # If main task is done - errored or not - all other tasks are canceled.
    # So we need to shield main task.
    REQUIRE_SHIELDING.add(asyncio.current_task())

    # install handler
    install_handler()

    # spawn tasks that will be shielded
    for n in range(3):
        REQUIRE_SHIELDING.add(asyncio.create_task(work(n)))

    # spawn tasks that won't be shielded, for comparison
    for n in range(3, 6):
        asyncio.create_task(work(n))

    # we'll need to keep main task alive just until tasks are done, excluding self.
    await asyncio.gather(*(REQUIRE_SHIELDING - {asyncio.current_task()}))

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
PID: 10778
[0] Task start!
[1] Task start!
[2] Task start!
[3] Task start!
[4] Task start!
[5] Task start!
Received SIGINT
Cancelling 3 out of 7
[3] Canceled!
[5] Canceled!
[4] Canceled!
[0] Task done!
[1] Task done!
[2] Task done!
```

#### asyncio + [aiorun](https://github.com/cjrh/aiorun) (All OS)

Demonstrating same thing as above.

```
"""
Task shielding demonstration with asyncio + aiorun, all OS
"""
import asyncio
import os

from aiorun import run, shutdown_waits_for


async def work(n):
    """Some random io intensive work to test shielding"""
    print(f"[{n}] Task start!")
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print(f"[{n}] Canceled!")
        return

    print(f"[{n}] Task done!")


async def main():
    print(f"PID: {os.getpid()}")
    child_tasks = []

    # spawn tasks that will be shielded
    child_tasks.extend(
        asyncio.create_task(shutdown_waits_for(work(n))) for n in range(3)
    )

    # spawn tasks without shielding for comparison
    child_tasks.extend(asyncio.create_task(work(n)) for n in range(3))

    # aiorun runs forever by default, even without any coroutines left to run.
    # We'll have to manually stop the loop, but can't use asyncio.all_tasks()
    # check as aiorun's internal tasks included in it run forever.
    # instead, keep child task spawned by main task and await those.
    await asyncio.gather(*child_tasks)
    asyncio.get_running_loop().stop()


run(main())
```

```
PID: 26548
[0] Task start!
[1] Task start!
[2] Task start!
[3] Task start!
[4] Task start!
[5] Task start!
Stopping the loop
[4] Canceled!
[5] Canceled!
[3] Canceled!
[1] Task done!
[0] Task done!
[2] Task done!
```

#### Switching to [trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (All OS)

Ground-up pure python asynchronous event loop [without callback soup](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#callback-soup-considered-harmful)

```py
"""
Task shielding demonstration with trio, all OS
"""
import os

import trio


async def work(n):
    """Some random io intensive work to test shielding"""
    print(f"[{n}] Task start!")
    try:
        await trio.sleep(10)

    except trio.Cancelled:
        print(f"[{n}] Canceled!")
        raise

    print(f"[{n}] Task done!")


async def shielded():
    # opening explicit concurrency context.
    # Every concurrency in trio is explicit, via Nursery that takes care of tasks.
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:

        # shield nursery from cancellation. Now all tasks in this scope is shielded.
        nursery.cancel_scope.shield = True

        # spawn tasks
        for n in range(3):
            nursery.start_soon(work, n)


async def main():
    print(f"PID: {os.getpid()}")

    try:
        async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
            nursery.start_soon(shielded)

            for n in range(3, 6):
                nursery.start_soon(work, n)

    except (trio.Cancelled, KeyboardInterrupt):
        # Nursery always make sure all child tasks are done - either canceled or not.
        # This try-except is just here to suppress traceback. Not quite required.
        print("Nursery Cancelled!")


trio.run(main)
```

```
PID: 23684
[3] Task start!
[4] Task start!
[5] Task start!
[0] Task start!
[1] Task start!
[2] Task start!
[3] Canceled!
[4] Canceled!
[5] Canceled!
[0] Task done!
[1] Task done!
[2] Task done!
Nursery Cancelled!
```

Below is a tiny bit in-depth ramble on *asyncio*'s signal handler flow.

---

### Pure asyncio's signal handling

Spent full day digging into this issue - tracing, searching, reading source codes, yet can't get a complete flow. Following flow is my guess.

##### Without custom signal handlers

1. Receives SIGINT
2. Somehow `signal._signal.default_int_handler` is called, raising `KeyboardInterrupt`

```py
# signal/_signal.py - probably C code
def default_int_handler(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """
    The default handler for SIGINT installed by Python.
    
    It raises KeyboardInterrupt.
    """
```

3. Exception propagates, `finally` block runs in `asyncio.run`, calling `asyncio.runners._cancel_all_tasks()`

```py
# asyncio.runners
def run(main, *, debug=None):
    ...
    loop = events.new_event_loop()
    try:
        events.set_event_loop(loop)
        if debug is not None:
            loop.set_debug(debug)
        return loop.run_until_complete(main)
    finally:
        try:
            _cancel_all_tasks(loop)  # <---- this is called
            loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
            loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_default_executor())
        finally:
            events.set_event_loop(None)
            loop.close()
```

4. `asyncio.runners._cancel_all_tasks()` cancel all tasks returned by `asyncio.all_tasks`

```py
# asyncio/runners.py
def _cancel_all_tasks(loop):
    to_cancel = tasks.all_tasks(loop)  # <---- gets all running tasks
    if not to_cancel:                  # internally list of weakref.WeakSet '_all_tasks'
        return

    for task in to_cancel:  # <---- cancels all of it
        task.cancel()

    loop.run_until_complete(tasks.gather(*to_cancel, return_exceptions=True))
    ...
```

At the end of execution, successful or not, any remaining tasks will receive cancellation in step 4 eventually.

Since that `asyncio.shield` [also adds shielded tasks to `_all_tasks`](https://www.roguelynn.com/words/asyncio-graceful-shutdowns/) it won't help either.

However, if we add custom handlers - things get a bit different.

##### With custom signal handlers

0. We add out custom signal handler via `asyncio.add_signal_handler`

```py
# asyncio/unix_events.py
class _UnixSelectorEventLoop(selector_events.BaseSelectorEventLoop):
    ...
    def add_signal_handler(self, sig, callback, *args):
        """Add a handler for a signal.  UNIX only.

        Raise ValueError if the signal number is invalid or uncatchable.
        Raise RuntimeError if there is a problem setting up the handler.
        """
        ...
        handle = events.Handle(callback, args, self, None)
        self._signal_handlers[sig] = handle  # <---- added to sig handler dict
        ...
```

1. Receives SIGINT
2. Somehow our event loop's `_handle_signal` is called, gets matching signal handler from dictionary, and add it as a callback

```py
# asyncio/unix_events.py
class _UnixSelectorEventLoop(selector_events.BaseSelectorEventLoop):
    ...
    def _handle_signal(self, sig):
        """Internal helper that is the actual signal handler."""
        handle = self._signal_handlers.get(sig)  # <---- fetches added handler
        if handle is None:
            return  # Assume it's some race condition.
        if handle._cancelled:
            self.remove_signal_handler(sig)
        else:
            self._add_callback_signalsafe(handle)  # <---- adds as callback
    ...
```

3. Our custom callback is called

Now default signal handler is not called, so KeyboardInterrupt haven't been raised, hence `asyncio.run`'s `try-finally` block hasn't proceeded to `finally` yet. Therefore no `asyncio.runners._cancel_all_tasks` call.

All tasks finally survived! cancel non-essential tasks manually in handler and we're good to go.