# Unable to cancel future - asyncio.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, python-asyncio

I have a signal handler defined that cancels all the tasks in the currently running asyncio event loop when the SIGINT signal is raised. In `main`, I have defined a new loop and the loop runs until the sleep function completes. I have used print statements inside `signal_handler` for better understanding as to what happens when an `asyncio task` is cancelled.
Below is my implementation,

```
import asyncio
import signal

class temp:  
        
    def signal_handler(self, sig, frame):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        tasks = asyncio.all_tasks(loop=loop)
        for task in tasks:
            print(task.get_name())   #returns the name of the task
            ret_val = asyncio.Future.cancel(task)    #returns True if task was just cancelled
            print(f"Return value : {ret_val}")
            print(f"Task Cancelled : {task.cancelled()}")   #returns True if task is cancelled
        return
                
            
    def main(self):
        try:
            signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.signal_handler)
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop=loop)
            loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(20))
        except asyncio.CancelledError as err:
            print("Cancellation error raised")
        finally:
            if not loop.is_closed():
                loop.close()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = temp()
    test.main()
```

**Expected Behaviour**:
When I raise a SIGINT at any time using `Ctrl+C`, the task (asyncio.sleep()) gets cancelled instantaneously and a CancellationError is raised and there is a graceful exit.

**Actual Behaviour**:
The CancellationError is raised after time `t` (in seconds) specified as a parameter in `asyncio.sleep(t)`. For Example, the CancellationError is raised after 20 secs for the above code.

**Unusual Observation**:
The behaviour of the code is in line with the Actual Behaviour when executed on `Windows`.

**`The issue described above is only happening on Linux`**.

What could be the reason for this ambiguous behaviour?

Comment: I assume from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) _This arranges for a CancelledError exception to be thrown into the wrapped coroutine on the next cycle of the event loop._ that linux is not running the event loop until the 20 sec has passed but that windows is. I see the same behaviour as you unless I add an extra co-routine that runs faster than 20sec.

Comment: FYI, windows does not implement signaling, therefore it's internals are quite different than that of *nix variant's (`Proactor Event Loop` vs `Selector Event Loop`). Not directly related, but it's different behaviors can also be seen [when it comes to protect tasks from cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72999861/10909029).